# What is your favorite "data analysis" cartoon?

Tags: references, teaching, humor

Data analysis cartoons can be useful for many reasons: they help communicate; they show that quantitative people have a sense of humor too; they can instigate good teaching moments; and they can help us remember important principles and lessons.

[This is one of my favorites:](https://xkcd.com/552/)

[image: XKCD irony about correlation and causation]

As a service to those who value this kind of resource, please share your favorite data analysis cartoon.  They probably don't need any explanation (if they do, they're probably not good cartoons!)  As always, *one entry per answer*. (This is in the vein of the Stack Overflow question *[What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon)*.)

P.S. Do not hotlink the cartoon without the site's permission please.

Comment: @sharpie: are jokes out?  We obviously don't want the entire site to be humor, but everyone benefits from a little educational humor in small doses.

Comment: @Sharpie, feel free to close or reopen according to your feelings! I agree with Shane, a bit is ok, but not too much. For example, this question already included a funny cartoon. The jokes question not really a funny joke....

Comment: These cartoons are useful too; they can be included in a lecture on a particular topic where you are trying to explain a concept (e.g. correlation/causation above).  A little humor can help to keep an audience engaged.

Comment: Could we clarify the problem with hotlinking referenced in the P.S.? Might need to fix some of these answers, if it's worth worrying about.

Comment: According to the [tour](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour), this question should be closed, since it is a question that has "too many possible answers" and since it is "primarily opinion-based". I'm not complaining, just surprised it has stayed open for this long.

Comment: I decided to recreate this on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/q/671249/218888). As it seems like a great idea for some levity in an otherwise serious environment. Here's hoping it survives!

Comment: Data Science analogy to cartoon in OP. Data Scientist: I went to data science bootcamp and learned how to find correlations in big data. Those insights can be converted into big money. Statistician: But many of those correlations are spurious. Correlation does not imply causation. Data Scientist: Don't give me none of that century old statistics mumbo-jumbo. This is big data. That means the data has everything. So by definition, all relationships in the data are correct. I ring the cash register while you snooze and lose, grandpa.

Comment: I wanted to vote down because this is not the site for such discussions but this is my favorite data cartoon, I had it in my office for a while.

Comment: wow! what a great post!

Answer (score 246):

Was XKCD, so time for Dilbert:

[image]

Source: http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Did anyone else notice that the tour guide changes colors between the second and third frames?

Comment: [On RANDU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANDU): "We guarantee that each number is random individually, but we don't guarantee that more than one of them is random."

Comment: Link not working, was it this one http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25 ?

Answer (score 229):

Another from [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/539/):
[image: ... okay, but because you said that, we're breaking up.]

Mentioned [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/02/cartoon.html) and [here](http://www.cerebralmastication.com/2009/02/box-plot-vs-violin-plot-in-r/).

Comment: You can't read this one without the alt text.  it said something like "But because of that we're totally breaking up"

Comment: @generic_user The alt text (mouseover text) reads: "... okay, but because you said that, we're breaking up."

Answer (score 211):

My favourite Dilbert cartoon:

[image]

Source: http://dilbert.com/strip/2008-05-07

Comment: Definitively my favorite cartoon about Data Mining

Comment: Link not working. Was it this one: http://dilbert.com/strip/2008-05-07 ?

Answer (score 199):

One more [Dilbert cartoon](http://dilbert.com/fast/2008-05-08/):

[image: http://dilbert.com/fast/2008-05-08/]
<sub>...</sub>

Comment: This one reminds me of the recent bailout in the States, where they just made up 700 billion number - they said they just wanted a really large number. :)

Comment: Fixed. I had to add some dots after the cartoon since SE didn't allow me to submit the changes :-\

Answer (score 182):

One of my favorites from [xckd](http://www.xkcd.com):

### Random Number

[image: RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the standard IEEE-vetted random number.]

> RFC 1149.5 specifies 4 as the standard IEEE-vetted random number.

Comment: But that isn't even prime!

Answer (score 156):

[image: XKCD: significant]

> 'So, uh, we did the green study again and got no link. It was probably a--' 'RESEARCH CONFLICTED ON GREEN JELLY BEAN/ACNE LINK; MORE STUDY RECOMMENDED!'

xkcd: [significant](http://xkcd.com/882/)

Comment: This is by far my favorite cartoon of all time. It's super educational. It really gets to the heart of the definition of a p-value. In fact, I bet that less than 10% the students who pass a college freshman "intro to stats" class get this joke, and this makes me sad.

Comment: Maybe so! Fortunately for freshmen, @Glen_b has offered [an excellent breakdown here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/88067/32036).

Comment: Great! But yellow appears twice :P

Comment: this is a pretty good joke as it clearly demonstrates why repeated multiple testing is dangerous. For anyone interested check out Bonferi correction to deal with this.

Answer (score 156):

[image: Normal Versus Paranormal Distribution]

From: **A visual comparison of normal and paranormal distributions** Matthew Freeman
*J Epidemiol Community Health* 2006;60:6. Lower caption says 'Paranormal Distribution' - no idea why the graphical artifact is occuring.

Comment: I think [this version](http://i.imgur.com/rrjJtoO.png) of the joke works better (from http://www.oneweirdkerneltrick.com), though apparently this version was seven years earlier.

Comment: this isn't really funny. it's more of a twist on english terms

Comment: @zero "A twist on English terms" describes a great many jokes

Comment: Yeah - I think all those jokes suck. There is no underlying statistical humour. This joke should be put on the English stackexchange instead.

Comment: @Phil: In the 2-dimensional version linked by Dougal, the "paranormal distribution" is indeed a (bizarrely truncated) distribution; so the joke has some statistical content. It doesn't work in one dimension, where your comment certainly applies.

Answer (score 144):

I just came across this and loved it:

[image]

(http://xkcd.com/795/).

Answer (score 133):

[image: Image at bp1.blogger.com.]

Comment: That's great.  The standard way of dealing with outliers.

Comment: Who's the artist?

Comment: This cartoon was drawn by [Ben Shabad](http://davidmlane.com/ben/cartoons.html)

Answer (score 125):

Another from [xkcd #833](http://xkcd.com/833/):

[image: And if you labeled your axes, I could tell you exactly how MUCH better.]

> And if you labeled your axes, I could tell you exactly how MUCH better.

Answer (score 118):

[image: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/extrapolating.png]

> By the third trimester, there will be hundreds of babies inside you.

Also from [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/605/)

Answer (score 111):

This isn't technically a cartoon, but close enough:

[image]

Comment: That's definitely my favorite. I always have to stop on this and laugh when scrolling over this page. It's just so bad!!

Comment: +1 'Natch, [Randal Munroe has a sweet variation on this](https://xkcd.com/688/).

Comment: Yep: a pie is a pie chart telling you how much pie is left.

Answer (score 106):

Nice.
The importance of variance when thinking about a population.

[image]

[Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2560&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+smbc-comics%2FPvLb+%28Saturday+Morning+Breakfast+Cereal+%28updated+daily%29%29)

Answer (score 103):

this too:
[image]

Comment: To be honest, those are the bad physicists. The good physicists stick around and make a name for themselves.

Comment: Yet it's amazing how often it works...

Comment: Economics defined

Answer (score 99):

There is [this one](http://www.isds.duke.edu/~mw/ABS04/Lecture_Slides/4.Stats_Regression.pdf) on Bayesian learning:

[image]

Comment: What's the source?

Comment: It was taken from Mike West's website: http://www.stat.duke.edu/~mw/fineart.html

Answer (score 94):

And another one from xkcd.

Title: **Self-Description**

[image]

The mouseover text:

> The contents of any one panel are
>   dependent on the contents of every
>   panel including itself. The graph of
>   panel dependencies is complete and
>   bidirectional, and each node has a
>   loop. The mouseover text has two
>   hundred and forty-two characters.

Answer (score 80):

Here is a nice one (the inadequacy about average ratings)
[image: http://xkcd.com/937/]

Comment: Kinda disappointed that Munroe did not work "[selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_bias)" into the text.

Answer (score 78):

Another one from [xkcd](http://xkcd.org/892/):

[image: Hell, my eighth grade science class managed to conclusively reject it just based on a classroom experiment. It's pretty sad to hear about million-dollar research teams who can't even manage that.]

Alt-text:

> Hell, my eighth grade science class managed to conclusively reject it just based on a classroom experiment. It's pretty sad to hear about million-dollar research teams who can't even manage that.

Answer (score 74):

Here's [another one from Dilbert](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2010-07-02/):

[image]

Comment: Looks like this one needs an updated image.

Answer (score 70):

[image]

http://andrewgelman.com/2011/12/suspicious-histograms/

Answer (score 66):

More about design and power than analysis, but I like this one

[image]

Answer (score 66):

I liked this one:

[image]

This is probably fun to show in class as well...

Answer (score 57):

A classic...

[image: Never discuss multiple testing without it]

Comment: "Because medical research findings can be difficult to reconcile, are not always pre-digested, and can seem overwhelming to us casual observers, let us make fun of those who dedicate their lives to obtaining them."

Comment: @rolando2 As a medical researcher, I find the sensationalist incompetence of mainstream science reporters hilarious.

Comment: There's a listserv from HealthNewsReview devoted to evaluating media handling of health research findings.

Comment: As a statistician, I find the sensationalist incompetence of mainstream "data analysts" hilarious.

Answer (score 57):

[image]

Source: unknown. Posted on flowingdata.com.

Comment: There could be a secondary y-axis labeled "Ballerina chicken with cloaca".

Answer (score 56):

[image]

[Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2328#comic)

Comment: yeah but.... this one isn't true... it mostly depends on how you parameterize the time variable $t$... i guess if you go back far enough, but come on...

Answer (score 55):

[image]

Found this one in the [comments on Andrew Gelman's blog](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2011/04/worst_statistic.html#comment-2512168).

Comment: This chart is wrong, correct percentage is about fifty-fifty.

Answer (score 54):

I found this [from a NoSQL presentation](http://www.erlang-factory.com/upload/presentations/282/neo4j-is-not-erlang-but-i-still-heart-you-2010-06-10.pdf), but the cartoon can be found directly at

http://browsertoolkit.com/fault-tolerance.png

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain this cartoon?

Answer (score 48):

Allright, I think this one is hilarious- but let's see if it passes the Statistical Analysis Miller test.

### Fermirotica

[image: I love how Google handles dimensional analysis. Stats are ballpark and vary wildly by time of day and whether your mom is in town.]

> I love how Google handles dimensional analysis.  Stats are ballpark and vary wildly by time of day and whether your mom is in town.

Comment: Statistical voyeurism? And there we were wondering what to call the site...

Answer (score 46):

From [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/893/):

[image]
This is data analysis in the form of a cartoon, and I find it particularly poignant.

> The universe is probably littered with the one-planet graves of cultures which made the sensible economic decision that there's no good reason to go into space--each discovered, studied, and remembered by the ones who made the irrational decision.

Answer (score 44):

Another one from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/388/):

[image: Coconuts are so far down to the left they couldn't be fit on the chart. Ever spent half an hour trying to open a coconut with a rock? Down with coconuts.]

Comment: Bananas are always tasty.

Comment: @AnonymousType and easy!

Comment: Where are persimmons?

Comment: @EngrStudent: they're simultaneously off both ends of the tasty scale.

Comment: Needs replication.

Comment: I'm surprised Durian isn't on here...

Comment: Unsure what to make of the tomatoes ranking low on tasty: perhaps Randall does not know about heirloom varieties?

Comment: I had this one posted on my door for about 7 years :)

Answer (score 39):

[Here](http://phd.kt.pri.ee/2009/08/11/captain-statistics-episode-1/)'s a somewhat more technical one.

[image]

Answer (score 39):

I don't think this one was posted yet... [image]

Comment: I like the percentages given in the third panel.

Answer (score 39):

Here is a very meaningful chart..

[image: Bizarro]

Answer (score 38):

From [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/701/):

[image: You don't use science to show that you are right, you use science to become right.]

If some people who really believe that everything should be scientifically tested would actually walk their talk than they this comic might even show an event that actually happens.

Answer (score 35):

Another one from xkcd:

[image]

Hover Text:

> Knuth Paper-Stack Notation: Write down the number on pages. Stack
>   them. If the stack is too tall to fit in the room, write down the
>   number of pages it would take to write down the number. THAT number
>   won't fit in the room? Repeat. When a stack fits, write the number of
>   iterations on a card. Pin it to the stack.

Comment: Interestingly enough, that suggestion (number of pages, stacks of paper, etc.) is effectively a pseudo log-scale.

Answer (score 31):

[image]​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: This is just one flag for torture never being funny, even indirectly or allusively.

Comment: @NickCox, sorry, my english is not enough to understand your sentence..

Comment: Personal opinion: Torture isn't funny.

Comment: @NickCox, come on, it's just numbers! :)

Comment: Your cartoon alludes to people suffering. In turn, I say: come on, you should not find that funny. I won't expand on the point.

Comment: @NickCox, how does my cartoon allude to *people* anyhow? Its about *data*, not people!

Comment: I can only infer that you don't know the meaning of the word "torture".

Comment: This is also why torture is no good for anyone, including the torturer.

Comment: @NickStauner I don't get this discussion. Is it that Nick Cox was rather sensitive, transfering the joke about suffering data to suffering people? How does your comment relate to this?

Comment: Oh, I wasn't commenting on the conversation, just the cartoon itself...

Comment: Ironically, this cartoon uses "torture" in a common, among statisticians, metaphorical sense of "analyze incorrectly". The humor comes from the fact that it just happens to recall a word meaning something else... But the cartoon isn't about torture, it's about abuse of statistical methods. Though, perhaps one might contend that *abuse* is also a serious and weighty matter, and for that matter, so is weight...

Answer (score 31):

[image: Figure 1. Guitar beaver + keyboard duck ≈ keytar platypus.]
From [tenso GRAPHICS](http://www.tensographics.com/), as [claimed on REDDIT](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/cdxzd/its_true/c0rxhqp).

Comment: I like that it took me a second, and then another second to get the second joke. :)

Answer (score 30):

[image]

[Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2440)

And the [votey](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=votey) (a sort of black-and-white epilogue unique to SMBC):

[image]

Answer (score 28):

A Frequentists vs. Bayesians cartoon from XKCD!

[image: http://xkcd.com/1132/]

Mouse-hover transcript:

> 'Detector! What would the Bayesian statistician say if I asked whether the--' [roll] 'I AM A NEUTRINO DETECTOR, NOT A LABYRINTH GUARD. SERIOUSLY, DID YOUR BRAIN FALL OUT?' [roll] '... Yes.'

Comment: I am not sure about this one ... the Frequentist Reasoning seems wrong to me but I cannot explain why :(.

Comment: Because of obvious trying to score a cheap point with deliberate misrepresentation, one of the few xkcd comics I don't like.

Comment: I'm biased towards the Bayesian interpretation, but the frequentist appears to me to be consistent with the standard frequentist interpretation. I hate null hypothesis significance testing, but if you want to go that route, it seems the null hypothesis is that the sun did not explode. If the null hypothesis is true, the chances of observing a "Yes" would indeed be $\frac{1}{36}$ (negligibly higher if you want to be pedantic and include the chance of a machine malfunction). So we've either seen a rare event and the sun is still there or the sun is gone. Many frequentists default to the latter.

Comment: Of course, using a threshold of $p < 0.05$ is ridiculous in this case, but unfortunately many frequentists don't think about other thresholds.

Comment: But if we follow the principle of "$H_0$ is what we want do disprove", then $H_0$=Sun did explode => prob is 1-1/36 => cannot reject $H_0$, which does not mean that $H_1$ is true. I guess this was an attempt to cover a physics joke, because the sun cannot become nova.

Comment: @steffen I would contend that using "$H_0$ = Sun did explode" is not really appropriate in this case.  The null hypothesis is supposed to be the **default** position, so unless I have an incredibly strong reason to believe otherwise, my default will be that the sun did not explode.

Comment: @MichaelMcGowan good point, I agree.

Comment: This is what Andrew Gelman thinks about this comic: http://andrewgelman.com/2012/11/16808/

Comment: And Larry Wasserman: http://normaldeviate.wordpress.com/2012/11/09/anti-xkcd/

Answer (score 27):

From [SMBC](http://www.smbc-comics.com):

[image]

Comment: Is it churlish to wince when I read "data is"?

Comment: Not churlish.  Petulant.

Comment: Not Petulant.  Literate.  ;)

Comment: I wince more that idea that all perspectives are subjectively situated is sad.

Comment: The only time I hear the word "datum" used by *scientists*, it is in the [geodetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum) sense. Perhaps I have a biased sample?

Answer (score 27):

This is not a cartoon, but a joke worth mentioning:

A statistic professor travels to a conference by plane. When he passes the security check, they discover a bomb in his carry-on-baggage. Of course, he is hauled off immediately for interrogation.

"I don't understand it!" the interrogating officer exclaims. "You're an accomplished professional, a caring family man, a pillar of your parish - and now you want to destroy that all by blowing up an airplane!"

"Sorry", the professor interrupts him. "I had never intended to blow up the plane."

"So, for what reason else did you try to bring a bomb on board?!"

"Let me explain. Statistics shows that the probability of a bomb being on an airplane is 1/1000. That's quite high if you think about it - so high that I wouldn't have any peace of mind on a flight."

"And what does this have to do with you bringing a bomb on board of a plane?"

"You see, since the probability of one bomb being on my plane is 1/1000, the chance that there are two bombs is 1/1000000. This way I am much safer..."

Comment: Independence!!!

Comment: @KHKim, we all know that, don't ruin a joke :)

Comment: But if you know that "there is a bomb" (yours) in the plane, which we may call event $A$, and you are willing to accept that the "existence of a second bomb" (event $B$) is independent of $A$, then $P(B\mid A)=P(B)=1/1000$. Always condition on what you know. And yeah, I deserve a $-1$ for screwing a good joke.

Comment: @Zen again, why do you explain this? Even the security check guy in the story understand this, intuitivelly... don't analyze a joke :-)

Comment: By the way, as far as I know, the person who first described this anecdote was none other than [Hugo Steinhaus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Steinhaus) (of the Steinhaus-Banach theorem fame) in his "Mathematical Kaleidoscope".

Comment: Thanks @January! Finally some interesting information :-)

Comment: Reminds me of Baldrick's Bullet: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKRxX3s3JlM

Comment: It's kind of hard to enjoy a stat joke when it's screaming "bad stat" at the same time!

Comment: This isn't a *cartoon*. It belongs in a different question.

Answer (score 27):

**Explaining Away**

Since these are a rather sampling theoretic set of cartoons so far, here's one for the Bayesians.  (Actually I set it as a class question last year.)

[image: Explaining Away]

Comment: XKCD link is https://xkcd.com/690/

Comment: Thanks. Changed the URL to the one recommended for embedding (not the one you suggest).

Answer (score 27):

[image]

Not a cartoon but the best way of not being confused about type I and II errors. And very funny IMHO

Answer (score 26):

[image]

"The bridge of life"

I took this image from [here](http://www.steinsaltz.me.uk/agingpage.html). This is a "Painting commissioned by Karl Pearson", [see](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/reprints/Turner-Hanley-JRSS-A.pdf). It is considered as a predecessor of the hazard function.

The 'Death' attempts to kill you at different ages using different sorts of weapons which are related to the "failure probability" at the corresponding age.

Comment: It would help dense people like me to see some brief explanation of how this is specifically related to data analysis.  Also, please acknowledge (or at least link to) the source: give credit where credit is due.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your comment. I added a bit of details in order to clarify its meaning and relationship with statistics.

Comment: Is this Avignon bridge?

Comment: @Tomas It looks similar indeed.

Answer (score 23):

This one may be a little too real for anyone involved in academic research...

[image: If all else fails, use "significant at the p > .05 level" and hope no one notices."]

[See the original here.](http://xkcd.com/1478/)

Comment: I like this XKCD, but Randall Munroe's implication about the value of p = exactly .050 is incorrect. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60825/is-a-p-value-of-0-04993-enough-to-reject-null-hypothesis explains why this is the case.

Comment: The difference between incorrect and correct here has measure zero :)

Answer (score 22):

Because It's PIE, make me laught LOL. hahaha http://portal-statistik.blogspot.com[image]

Answer (score 21):

This one is a hit :)! I've seen it a few days ago.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

[image]

Sorry it is in Dutch! Translation

- Greetings new recruits! Welcome to the training camp for gladiators
- Be warned! One in three of you does not survive the training
- 33.3% ... That's not so bad

Comment: As a pointer to why we should think about *conditional* probabilities (and from then on, to why tools like logistic regression are useful for predicting risk) this is an excellent cartoon.

Answer (score 18):

[image: pie chart example]

an 'easy to digest' pie chart example for Rick Astley fans that my students seem to enjoy

Comment: Are those mutually exclusive events? :-)

Comment: Reminds me of the "Hey Jude" flowchart: https://flowingdata.com/2011/01/21/hey-jude-flowchart/

Comment: Using very similar shades of colour for different responses - naughty boy!

Answer (score 16):

From [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/815/):

Almost a Chi square...

[image]

> As the CoKF approaches 0, productivity goes negative as you pull OTHER people into chair-spinning contests.

Comment: ?? This seems to have nothing to do with stats.  (The curve is modeled after energy potentials in physics, not after anything in stats.)

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Quite a trend (I am the one on the left with the laptop)

[image: Big data no idea]

Answer (score 15):

No one put up a cartoon from the cartoon guide to statistics.  I like many of them from there and I used a number of them in one of my books.  The one that seems to get the most laughs when I use it in a lecture is the one with the statistician going out on a first date.  Their comments and thoughts about the making decisions on the menu with the statistician assessing probabilities and the woman just choosing what she likes makes it really hilarious.

[image]

Comment: Is it this one, Michael?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot Bill. I didn't have any idea how I could paste it in. Is uppose I could have scanned it in to a file and then tried pasting it. That would have been a lot of trouble. Is that what you did? There are a few more scenes in that one that are also pretty funny.  But this gets the idea across.

Comment: Being familiar with this book, it was easy to look it up on the Web.  I quickly found one of those versions (on a reseller page) that give you access to selected pages.  This image is from such a page, so no scanning (on my part) was necessary.

Comment: Okay, sometimes that is possible but I think more often scanning would be necessary.

Answer (score 15):

I wonder if it's OK to use %-points as an abbreviation of percentage points.

http://xkcd.com/985/

[image: percentage points]

Answer (score 15):

[image: I liked this !]

I liked this one. Found on [this](http://ianchadwick.com/blog/tag/casino/) page.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

This one makes you think about the importance of thinking about conditional probabilities. Now I don't know what to make of the twist at the end.

Answer (score 14):

From [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1007/):

[image]

> Though 100 years is longer than a lot of our resources.

Answer (score 13):

[image: No]

Life...

"Hearing something a hundred times isn't better than seeing it once"

Answer (score 12):

[image]

John Deering, [Strange Brew](http://www.thecomicstrips.com/store/add_strip.php?iid=45773)

Comment: I admit, I don't get it.

Comment: I think it's that for any other type of presentation, you'd have started by telling a joke. But since mathematicians (or statisticians, here) only think and speak in terms of formulas, this was their (still lame) joke-analogue for opening a presentation.

Comment: Let epsilon be less than 0

Answer (score 12):

My favorite is Sidney Harris he has many great cartoons[image]

Answer (score 12):

Yes, let's not jump to random forest before we work on some simpler branches!

http://www.gocomics.com/andertoons/2015/12/17 
[image]

Answer (score 11):

Not exactly data analysis but I had a chuckle.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

This one might be useful when introducing the concept of experimental and control groups.

http://www.gocomics.com/looseparts/2015/12/08

[image]

Answer (score 10):

http://www.gocomics.com/frazz/2012/03/27/
[image]

Answer (score 10):

"Curve-Fitting Methods and the Messages They Send" by xkcd: https://xkcd.com/2048/

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Bush and Gorbachev in a statistical golf cart] My favorite was created by Emanuel Parzen, appearing in [IMA preprint 663](http://www.ima.umn.edu/preprints/July90Series/663.pdf), but this illustrates my degenerate sense of humor.

Gorbachev says to Bush: "that's a very nice golfcart, Mr. President. Can it change how statistics is practiced?" etc. hahahah.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.gocomics.com/strangebrew/2011/10/11/

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Note: this is from SMBC ([Saturday Morning Breakfast Cereal](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php)) by Zach Weiner.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A new one from XKCD, suggesting a preference for a particular plot type:

https://xkcd.com/1967/

[image: Strictly speaking, 'violin' refers to the internal structure of the data. The external portion visible in the plot is called the 'viola.']

hover text: *Strictly speaking, 'violin' refers to the internal structure of the data. The external portion visible in the plot is called the 'viola.'*

Answer (score 7):

**Correlation does not imply causation!**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Statisticians aren't easily cowed.

[image: Far Side cartoon by Gary Larson]

Answer (score 6):

Source: http://www.gocomics.com/andertoons/2014/06/15#.U54J7iigS8A by Mark Anderson, June 15, 2014.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: http://www.gocomics.com/baldo/2011/08/06]

Comment: Shouldn't it be x-variable?

Answer (score 4):

More of a math cartoon than a data analysis cartoon, but also one that makes you think a bit.

http://www.gocomics.com/barneyandclyde/2013/11/12/?view=full#.UoI73-KQOfs 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Gahan Wilson died this week; having presented many a confusing graph myself, I can relate to this: [image]

Answer (score 3):

Overfitting -explanation in a picture (original cartoon) [image: Overfitting -explanation in a picture]

Comment: Giving a source would be good practice. Pity about the typo (split infinitives are acceptable to me).

Comment: I created the cartoon. Got that result, found it amazing and added the text. What is the typo? How would you phrase the titles?

Comment: Fine; so you are fully entitled to claim "(original cartoon)". You fixed the typo I saw (allways for always).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

True if $P=NP$

[image]

True if $P \ne NP$

This is  great one about solving NP-complete problems. They come up a lot on the job, like efficient scheduling or how to select the optimal configuration among a number of various options for which you have to search through them all to find the best one.

Think about it anytime you need to cop out of something difficult at work!

Answer (score 3):

From [Richard MceElreath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_McElreath)'s Twitter (October 8th, 2022; [source](https://twitter.com/rlmcelreath/status/1582368904529137672))

[image: Estimand - estimator - estimate]

Answer (score 2):

Draw your own data , found it in the below link

[New Year] : http://robertgrantstats.co.uk/drawmydata.html

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Jenkin math joke]

The cartoon can actually be found here https://thejenkinscomic.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is for the [queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory) people. or should I say queue-cumbers ;)

[image: ![](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fyot4whki56631.jpg)]

([source](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fi.redd.it%2Fyot4whki56631.jpg))

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Loose Parts by Dave Blazek 1/10/2018

Answer (score 1):

Frequentism vs Bayesian meet causal inference.

[image]

[image]

([source](https://github.com/rmcelreath/causal_salad_2021/blob/main/Slides_Part_1.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Illustration by Julia Suits, author of The Extraordinary Catalog of Peculiar Inventions, and The New Yorker cartoonist.