# Gaussian Mixture and K-Means ?! a big challenge?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, mathematical-statistics, k-means, gaussian-mixture-distribution

This is taken from Tom. Mitche Material as Old-Exam.

I think the (2) is true and not (3). Who can verify me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(3) is correct. In k-means, the distance is computed independently of the cluster with the same function for all clusters. Thus, if a datapoint x is equally distant to two centers, it probability to belonging to either cluster is 0.5

Yet, if you are using - as explained in (2) - a different covariance matrix for each cluster, the probability for the datapoint x is higher to belong to the cluster with the higher $r_i$ (a bigger covariance matrix).

Further great input and explanation can be found in the answers to this question:
[How to understand the drawbacks of K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means)