# What is the good method to select initial seeds in K-means?

Tags: data-mining, k-means

in text documents clustering when k-means using as base algorithm, and VSM is a matrix for doc-term weighted by tf-idf, what is the best metric can be used for select an optimal initialization points (seed points ) where clustering procedure starting from these points ?

Comment: k-means is mostly heuristic based and has many drawbacks in comparison to model based clustering. You should review http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means/133694#133694

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common approach is to use random initialization points, and run the algorithm multiple times, keeping the seed that minimizes your clustering error metric.