# What are the advantages of Louvain method versus K-means for clustering sparse data?

Tags: clustering, k-means, modularity

I would like to better understand the strengths of the Louvain method versus K-means for high-dimensional sparse data (e.g. zero-inflated negative binomial gene expression counts or natural language processing matrices).

A common procedure is to reduce dimensionality with PCA and then cluster on principal component space. In this context, what is the main value of the Louvain method versus K-means?

From [How to understand the drawbacks of K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means), aside of the obvious advantage of not relying on the assumption of K number of clusters (albeit, the Louvain method relies on parameters like the number of relevant nearest-neighbors to build a graph), I conclude that the Louvain method, on the contrary, does not assume equal size, density or shape of the clusters.

Is this intuition correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is correct.
The Louvain method is a-parametric, and requires no prior assumptions on the graph.

However, the main difference is thet K-means (and most others) work on *data points embedded in some space*, while Louvain works on data points *connected by a graph*. Now, if you have points in some space and want to create a graph out of them - the graph itself might be composed through some heuristic or assumption.

If a graph representation is already a 'natural' representation for your data (maybe gene expression counts have a clear correlation network structure?), the Louvain method is appropriate.

If not, you might want to look at, for example [DBScan](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html), which also doesn't require the number of clusters (but does require some other parameters).