# Statistically, how to find a subset of values which seems to have same magnitude?

Tags: clustering, similarities, methodology

**Data Set Description**

I have a data set where students' spent time on study is available.

[image: Data set]

In this table, student 4 to student 10 seem to spend similar amount of time on study. There is very little variation.

**My Question**

Is there any statistical method by which I can say *"Yes, student 4,5,6,7,8,9,10 spending time on study is similar"*.

Or

Is there any method by which I can say *"Yes, student 4,5,6,7,8,9,10 spending time on study is not significantly different."*.

**How Did I Try?**

I think methods like t-test, ANOVA, Kruskal can not be applied in this case. I was thinking about variance which can say about this. But I am really not sure. I have searched using different keywords in Google, but sorry to say, I did not find the answer.

Comment: k-means clustering is a method of vector quantization that aims to partition n observations into k clusters. Have you tried to cluster the vector of observation into 3 clusters using k-means?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I forgot thinking about this method. I will study on this and will let you know.

Comment: @JesperforPresident: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it. You could also suggest one-dimensional clustering in general, [k-means is not always the best choice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133656/1352).

Comment: No i do not, someone else can do it. Sorry do not have time. Otherwise i think it can be closed as duplicate since i guess some else has explained how clustering algorithms work.

Comment: @JesperforPresident Thanks. Your suggestion solved my problem.

Comment: Cool, happy to hear, maybe you could then post your solution as an answer, with a small scale coding example if you have the time, then we can closte the question (site statistics you know).