# Can DBSCAN overcome the drawbacks of K-means?

Tags: clustering, k-means, dbscan

We have a great post to discuss [the drawbacks of K-means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133656/how-to-understand-the-drawbacks-of-k-means).

Can DBSCAN overcome these drawbacks? and what are the drawbacks of DBSCAN?

Comment: DBSCAN meets certain k-means limits. Among them, DBSCAN does not need to set the cluster number a priori, and it can identify irregular, not necessarily spherical, cluster shapes. Nevertheless, it has difficulties identifying nested clusters, which has led to other versions such as OPTICS and Hdbscan.