# Is my understanding of Expected Value of a Random Variable correct?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

I have come up with the following understanding about Expectation of RV.

Please, correct me if I am wrong.

**Definition:**
Expected value of a RV says that, if a random experiment is repeated n number of times, what would be the value that you expect to see most of the times.
Expected value of a Random Variable is a value. It is not a probability.

**Example**:
In case of a dice, if the dice is rolled $n$ number of times, the value we would see most of the times is 3.5.

**Calculation:**
We don't have to repeat the same experiment $n$ number of times to find the expected value of a random variable. It can be done using the random variable and its associated probability distribution.
In case of a dice,

$ \sum_{x=1}^6 x(1/6) = 1*(1/6) + 2*(1/6) + 3*(1/6) + 4*(1/6) + 5*(1/6) + 6*(1/6) = 3.5 $

**Continuous Case**

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with density function $f_X(x),$ then the expectation of $X$ is
$\displaystyle E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\,f_X(x)\,dx$

If $Y=g(X)$ is a function of $X$(i.e. a **density function**)$,$ then
$\displaystyle E(Y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,f_X(x)\,dx$

**Edit:**

After reading comments and answers,

Definition:

Expected value of a RV says that, if a random experiment is repeated n number of times, what would be the average value of the outcomes.

Expected value of a Random Variable is a value. It is not a probability.

Example:

In case of a dice, if the dice is rolled $n$ number of times, the average value of the outcomes would be 3.5.

Comment: This definition is *wrong*, it defines *mode*, not EV. Consider a fair coin (0 - tails, 1 - heads), it's expected value is 1/2 * 0 + 1/2 * 1 = 0.5. You will *never* see value of 0.5 since this variable has only values in {0, 1}.

Comment: @Tim, How can I correct my definition in its current form?

Comment: I, for one, have *never* seen a value of 3.5 on a die.

Comment: @whuber, Is my edit correct now?

Comment: Your edit, which reflects the answer you have received, expresses a *derived result*: it is a (qualitative) statement of the weak law of large numbers.  Although that certainly can help with understanding, it is not a definition of expected value.  Your original "example" still expresses the bizarre idea that a die can actually exhibit a value of 3.5! The expected value is a property of a model for your experiment (a die roll), as I have explained in various answers such as the one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30330/919.

Answer (score 5):

The expected value can be thought of as *the long-run average*. If you roll your die many, many times, and look at the *average* of the rolls, you will end up close to 3.5.

This is not the value that you expect to see most often. This would be the *mode* of the distribution (in the discrete case - for a continuous distribution, any particular value has the same probability of zero). After all, you will *never* see a roll of 3.5 with your standard six-sided die.

Comment: How can I correct my definition in its current form?

Comment: The first sentence of the Wikipedia article is helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

Comment: Is my **Continuous Case** correct?

Comment: See whuber's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to help - you put $n$ in your definition, but this is exactly what we don't want.  Since $n$ is never referenced elsewhere, its presence serves to inform the reader of your definition that the experiment is repeated a finite number of times.  So, we can either remove $n$ altogether and state that the experiment is repeated infinitely many times (which is a problem logically) or we can leave $n$ right where it is and state that the expectation is the *limit* of the average of the values as $n\to\infty$.  That is, in your dice example, let's take the average of $n$ values.  As we increase $n$, the average gets closer and closer to $3.5$.

Comment: This is a statement of a law of large numbers, but it does not define the expectation (which seems to be the focus of your interest). No mathematical definition of expectation employs a limit over an infinite sequence of experiments.  For discrete finite random variables, like the one describing the roll of a die, the definition is a finite sum: no limits are needed at all.