# recommendation for humor book on statistics

Tags: references, humor

I am looking for a humor book on statistics.

The intent is **not** to learn statistics.

I am rather thinking about funny statistical facts, funny statistical quotes, etc.

Any recommendation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Statistics Jokes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/statistics-jokes)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if such question fits into the category of an acceptable question on this site, but I would strongly urge you to have a look at [How to lie with Statistics](https://www.amazon.in/How-Lie-Statistics-Darrell-Huff/dp/0393310728) and [Spurious correlations](https://www.amazon.in/Spurious-Correlations-Tyler-Vigen/dp/0316339431).

Comment: The Huff book is overrated in my view. His dictum that graph axes should always show zero is over-simplified.  It was first published in 1954, but even in recent reprints in the US several of the cartoons  show people smoking (and, believe it or not, that includes babies smoking). I regard that as poor taste. The publishers (WW Norton) have silently corrected some language uses not acceptable now, but not that. The cartoons in the British version from Penguin were completely new as long ago as 1973!

Answer (score 0):

Steve Selvin published a book this year which certainly contains some jokes.

The one review published to date on Amazon.com is lukewarm and makes alternative recommendations. (Full disclosure: I wrote it.)

[https://www.amazon.com/Joy-Statistics-Elementary-Statistical-Applications/dp/019883344X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/019883344X)