# Do the principal values of higher moments exist for the Cauchy distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, moments, cauchy-distribution

It is known that the [Cauchy distribution has undefined moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Explanation_of_undefined_moments), and that the expectation has a principal Cauchy value $\operatorname{PV}\left( \mathbb{E} [X] \right)$ of zero.

I wonder if $\operatorname{PV}\left( \mathbb{E} \left[ (X - \operatorname{PV}\left( \mathbb{E} [X] \right))^n \right] \right)$ exists for all $n$, or if there is a highest principal Cauchy moment for the Cauchy distribution.

Do all the higher moment expectations have defined principal Cauchy values for the Cauchy distribution?

---

The first simplification of the above is to note that $\operatorname{PV} \left(\mathbb{E}[X]\right) = 0 \implies \operatorname{PV}\left( \mathbb{E} \left[ (X - \operatorname{PV}\left( \mathbb{E} [X] \right))^n \right] \right) = \operatorname{PV}\left( \mathbb{E} \left[ X^n \right] \right)$.

From the definition of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution) and the [Cauchy principal value](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html) we have

$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{0-\epsilon} x^n \frac{1}{\pi \gamma \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{x-x_0}{\gamma} \right)^2 \right]}dx + \int_{0+\epsilon}^{\infty} x^n \frac{1}{\pi \gamma \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{x-x_0}{\gamma} \right)^2 \right]}dx \right].$

So my question reduces to whether the above expression is defined.

---

Wolfram Alpha [tells me](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+x%5En%2F%28pi+*+gamma+*+%281+%2B+%28%28x-m%29%2Fgamma%29%5E2%29%29+dx) that

$\int x^n \frac{1}{\pi \gamma \left[ 1 + \left(\frac{x-x_0}{\gamma} \right)^2 \right]}dx = \frac{\gamma x^{n+1}}{2 \pi \sqrt{- \gamma^2} (n+1)} \left( \frac{_2F_1 \left(1, n+1;n+2;\frac{x}{m - \sqrt{- \gamma^2}} \right)}{m-\sqrt{- \gamma^2}} - \frac{_2F_1 \left(1, n+1;n+2;\frac{x}{m + \sqrt{- \gamma^2}} \right)}{m + \sqrt{- \gamma^2}} \right) + C$

where $_2F_1 (\cdot, \cdot ; \cdot ; \cdot )$ is a [hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: That's a useless version of the principal value, unless you are interested in *negative* $n.$  But since you ask about "highest," that would suggest you are contemplating *positive* $n.$

Comment: @whuber Oops, I must have missed something. I am interested in positive $n$. Something wrong in the Wolfram Alpha output, or elsewhere?

Comment: @whuber I saw your comment below. Makes sense.

Comment: That's the *indefinite* integral.  You have to take limits as $|x|\to \infty,$ where $x^{n+1}$ diverges.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The odd integral moments have principal values of zero while the even integral moments have infinite principal values.**

---

By definition, the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyPrincipalValue.html) [w.r.t. infinity] of an integral over the real line is

$$\operatorname{pv}\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^R g(x)\,\mathrm{dx}.$$

When $g$ is antisymmetric -- that is, $g(x) = -g(x)$ for all $x,$ obviously the right hand side is always zero, whence its limit is zero.

The Cauchy density is proportional to $1/(1+x^2),$ which is symmetric about $0.$  Consequently, for any *antisymmetric* integrable function $h,$

$$g(x)  = \frac{h(x)}{1+x^2}$$

is also integrable and antisymmetric, whence

$$\operatorname{pv} \int_\mathbb R \frac{h(x)}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = 0.$$

This is the case for $h(x) = x^{2k+1}$ when $k$ is a natural number.  It is not the case when $h(x) = x^{2k}.$  With $k=0,$ the integral converges, but for $k\ge 1$ use the simple fact that when $|x|\ge 1,$

$$\frac{x^{2k}}{1+x^2} \ge \frac{x^{2k}}{x^2+x^2} = \frac{1}{2}x^{2k-2} \ge \frac{1}{2}$$ to estimate

$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{-R}^R \frac{x^{2k}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x &\ge \lim_{R\to\infty}\left(\int_{-R}^{-1} + \int_1^R\right) \frac{x^{2k}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\ge \lim_{R\to\infty}\left(\int_{-R}^{-1} + \int_1^R\right) \frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} R - 1 =\infty.
\end{aligned}$$

---

A similar argument by symmetry handles the case of $negative$ integral $n,$ but now the principal value is computed by excising a small neighborhood $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ around zero and taking the limit (from above) as $\epsilon\to 0.$  Again there's cancellation for odd $n$ but divergence for even $n.$  Alternatively, change variables from $x$ to $1/x,$ which reduces the integral to the form explicitly considered here.