# Improper integrals of symmetric functions

Tags: integral, calculus

First time poster here, so I apologize for any formatting errors. I recently came across the improper integral ∫xdx from -∞ to ∞ and have had a hard time understanding why it isn't zero. My approach is as follows.

lim t ->∞ ∫xdx from -t to t

lim t->∞ 1/2(t^2-t^2)

lim t->∞ (0) = 0

Where am I going wrong in my reasoning? Every source I've been able to find has said otherwise but the explanations (especially those regarding Cauchy's Principal Value) are punching a little above my weight. Can anyone give me a *relatively* simple explanation besides such integrals simply diverge when any component diverges?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1113833/493872

Comment: That is precisely the explanation I said didn't help much. If both components diverge in opposite and exactly the same way, it still seems like it ought to be 0. What causes this to not be the case?

Comment: You aren't applying the definition correctly.  The integral is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{a\to-\infty}\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x.$$  That's a *double* limit in which the endpoints independently vary.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569481 for an example of working with principal values.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!