# Provide an example of a dataset where maximum likelihood is inapplicable as third moments and fourth moments "assumptions" do not apply

Tags: maximum-likelihood, dataset, assumptions, moments, definition

> An additional complication arises with estimation, since maximum likelihood estimation may not be feasible without making unrealistically strong ?????"assumptions"????? about third‐ and higher order moments--Analysis of longitudinal multiple‐source binary data using generalized estimating equations
> LM O'Brien, GM Fitzmaurice - Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series C …, 2004

They do not prove that their dataset does not satisfy the parametric distributional assumptions of the maximum likelihood approach so this paper supposes without proof maximum likelihood is not feasible.

https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1046/j.0035-9254.2003.05296.x

How do you prove a dataset does not satisfy maximum likelihood's distributional assumptions as the third and fourth moments do not satisfy XYZ criteria?

I have never heard that the maximum likelihood approach is inapplicable when your assumptions about 3rd and fourth and nth moments do not apply. Where do they come up with these ideas?

Comment: A useful thing to consider would estimating the mean of a uniform(a,b) density. If you used a normal probability model, you *would* get an unbiased estimate of the mean, but it would not be conditional on the sufficient statistic, and so it doesn't achieve the Cramer Rao lower bound.  To actually maximize a likelihood, you need the correct probability model for the data, that means that every moment of the distribution needs to be correct.

Comment: @AdamO I think your comment is suitable as an answer. Maybe also note that includes distributions like the Cauchy distribution, in which none of the moments are finite. (Although principal values of odd moments of Cauchy variables exist and are zero (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/569481/do-the-principal-values-of-higher-moments-exist-for-the-cauchy-distribution)).