# How to prove that in a linear model with an interaction term, centering the covariates doesn't impact the estimate of interaction coefficient?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, interaction, linear-model

So if the model is $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{i1} +  \beta_2 x_{i2} + \beta_{12} x_{i1} x_{i2} + \epsilon_i$, how can it be proved that the estimate and standard error for $\beta_{12}$ the same if we center $x_{.1}$ and $x_{.2}$ ?

Comment: This is a problem I am going through in a class I am auditing and I am unable to prove it. The result is supposed to hold ONLY with centering, not standardising as well. Ie in    lm(Sepal.Length ~ scale(Petal.Length, scale = F) * scale(Petal.Width,scale = F), iris)  will have the same interaction term as     lm(Sepal.Length ~ scale(Petal.Length) * scale(Petal.Width), iris)

Comment: @FransRodenburg the question is about centering alone, not centering and scaling to unit standard deviation as in your code. (Default is `center=TRUE`, `scale=TRUE`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean centering interaction terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417029/mean-centering-interaction-terms). The example there is for centering only one of 2 interacting variables, but just try centering both in the first equation presented in the answer.

Comment: @EdM Yeah that does answer the question, thanks!