# Whats the motivation to demean variables when estimating an interaction effect?

Tags: regression, centering

I am trying to estimate a regression model where I am interested in the effect of a certain magnitude, probability and expected value (probability * magnitude ) on reaction times. I was told that it is necessary to demean probability and magnitude before estimating its product. Can anyone give me an intuition in why you would use ev=demean(prob)*demean(mag)?

Thanks!

Laurie

Comment: It reduces correlation between main effects and interaction effects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean centering interaction terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417029/mean-centering-interaction-terms) You don't _have_ to, it just puts the single-predictor coefficients into more interpretable ranges.