# Post-hoc tests for unexpected outcome of binomial models

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, modeling, post-hoc

This may be too abstract for SE, in which case I will post in other forums.

I am running a binomial `glm`, where my response variables should be `A` and `B`. Response `A` is actually a grouping of `A1` and `A2`. I accidentally ran the binomial model with `A1`, `A2`, and `B` as my responses. I understand that if you run a binomial model (in `lme4`) with more than 2 response types, it will classify the first level as Failure, and all of the other levels as Success. As such, my 2 levels are `A1` and (`A2`, `B`).

I would expect that `A1` and `A2` are more similar, and so a model differentiating `A` vs `B` would be better fit than a model differentiating `A1` vs `A2` and `B`. However, I get more significant predictors when I run the model that groups `A2` and `B`, although the log-likelihood is better for the model differentiating `A` vs `B`.

I have reproduced the output below, and am wondering which post-hoc tests I should run to drill down into these results. I also see that the degrees of freedom are different in each model.

Model 1 - `A` vs `B`:

```
Call:
glm(formula = SQ_DA.2 ~ pre_utt_gap + utt_IKI * utt_speed + edit_ct, 
    family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = study1a.SQ.2.df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.6524   0.4943   0.5830   0.6505   1.1996  

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        0.886209   0.036701  24.147  < 2e-16 ***
pre_utt_gap       -0.090382   0.026356  -3.429 0.000605 ***
utt_IKI           -0.077471   0.046980  -1.649 0.099142 .  
utt_speed         -0.159251   0.035318  -4.509 6.51e-06 ***
edit_ct            0.020672   0.005083   4.067 4.77e-05 ***
utt_IKI:utt_speed  0.032871   0.024022   1.368 0.171202    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 3320.2  on 3591  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 3260.4  on 3586  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3272.4

> logLik(model1)
'log Lik.' -1630.184 (df=6)
```

Model 2 - `A1` vs `A2` and `B1`:

```
Call:
glm(formula = SQ_DA.3 ~ pre_utt_gap + utt_IKI * utt_speed + edit_ct, 
    family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = study1a.SQ.2.df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5925  -1.0244  -0.9236   1.3036   1.8997  

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)       -0.176418   0.031157  -5.662 1.49e-08 ***
pre_utt_gap        0.082588   0.022572   3.659 0.000253 ***
utt_IKI            0.098559   0.040861   2.412 0.015863 *  
utt_speed          0.134524   0.030912   4.352 1.35e-05 ***
edit_ct           -0.015926   0.003912  -4.071 4.68e-05 ***
utt_IKI:utt_speed  0.005229   0.021416   0.244 0.807104    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4843.1  on 3591  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 4792.9  on 3586  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4804.9

> logLik(model2)
'log Lik.' -2396.439 (df=6)
```

Any suggestions as to where I should look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra "significant" predictor in the second model, `utt_IKI`, is involved in an interaction with `utt_speed`. It can be misleading to evaluate the individual regression coefficient for a predictor involved in an interaction.

In the first model, although the interaction isn't "statistically significant" by the p < 0.05 criterion, it's of a reasonable magnitude. It's quite possible that a Wald test combining the two coefficients involving `utt_IKI` would be significant. Think of the interaction term in the first model as taking some "credit" away from `utt_IKI` by itself (which is evaluated at the reference/0 level of `utt_speed`), while in the second model the interaction is negligible so that there is nothing hiding the contribution of `utt_IKI` to outcome.

If `utt_speed` is a continuous predictor, you could probably re-center it to make the `utt_IKI` coefficient pass the (irrelevant, in this case) p < 0.05 criterion. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/417159/28500) as one illustration of what can be going on.

If you think that there is a reason to treat all of `A1`, `A2` and `B` separately, you could do a multinomial or ordinal regression with all three as possible outcomes, depending on whether those categories have an inherent order to them.

Comment: Thanks! This is extremely helpful. If I do run a multinomial model with the 3 responses, what's the best way to compare it to the binomial model? Should I just use R^2 or some other goodness of fit?

Comment: @Adam_G R^2 isn't so helpful for examining goodness-of-fit of a binomial or multinomial model. At least that's true of the usual R^2 measures; there are some types of ["pseudo-R^2"](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-what-are-pseudo-r-squareds/) for models fit by maximum likelihood. Do your three outcome categories have a natural ordering, like `A1` < `A2` < `B` in some sense? Then you should use ordinal regression. Also, ask yourself what specific hypothesis you want to test: what does it mean to compare a model predicting 3 outcomes to one predicting only 2?

Comment: I'm comparing types of sentences, and how people type them (all the predictors are typing patterns/timings). In this case A1=Statement-non-opinion, A2=Statement-opinion, and A3=Question. A vs B is testing Statement vs Question. So in answer to your question, there is no inherent order.

Comment: @Adam_G then think about which really is the "predictor" here. If people are given different types of sentences to type, then type of sentence would seem to be the independent/predictor variable, while "how people type them" would seem to be the set of dependent/outcome variables. Then you could do a true "multivariate" analysis of variance that takes into account correlations among the outcomes. Also, if the same individual is given multiple sentences to type, you need to take that correlation within individuals into account in the model, for example with a random-effects model.

Comment: My experiment was actually a spontaneous conversation; no one was given anything to type. In this case my question is "Are there significant differences in the way people type statements vs questions?" The 2nd half of my study will actually be `typing-pattern ~ sentence-type`, to answer the question of whether sentence types have distinct typing signatures, even if some of those signatures are  the same for some sentence types (there are 10 different types).