# Interpreting regression and variable set-up

Tags: r, regression, interaction, panel-data, variable

Im working on a quantile regression model where I look at how imports (*imp*<sub>i,t</sub>) of intermittent electricity (*int*<sub>i,t</sub>) such as wind solar from country i in period t impact day ahead prices in Norway in period t. My current model can be simplified to this:

price<sub>t</sub> ~ imp<sub>i,t</sub> + int<sub>i,t</sub> + imp<sub>i,t</sub>*int<sub>i,t</sub>

However, i´m not entirely certain about the implications of modelling it this way. For instance, imports can have a "main effect" on price but intermittent generation should only have an effect on price if its imported. When I look at the coefficients it seems that the int<sub>i,t</sub> is a lot more significant than the interaction which is likely due to the imported flows (in MWh) being quite small. But in theory, that variable shouldnt be that significant because it cant have an isolated main effect on price. Could I model this in a better way? Or am I interpreting the three coefficients wrong?

If for example
imp<sub>i,t</sub> = 0.1 
int<sub>i,t</sub> = -0.01 
imp<sub>i,t</sub>*int<sub>i,t</sub> = -0.000005

Should I interpret it as -0.01-0.000005+0.1 is the effect of importing intermittent from that country? All variables are continous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your observation:

> When I look at the coefficients it seems that the *int*<sub>i,t</sub> is a lot more significant than the interaction which is likely due to the imported flows (in MWh) being quite small. But in theory, that variable shouldnt be that significant because it cant have an isolated main effect on price.

comes from the attempt to interpret a so-called "main effect" for a predictor involved in an interaction. That can easily lead to confusion.

With the interaction term, the coefficient for *int*<sub>i,t</sub> represents its association with outcome when *inp*<sub>i,t</sub> = 0. The "significance" of that "main effect" coefficient is for a difference of the estimate from 0 when *inp*<sub>i,t</sub> = 0. If you centered the *inp*<sub>i,t</sub> values, the coefficient for *int*<sub>i,t</sub> would change, and thus its difference from a value of 0. There's a simple explanation on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/417029/28500).

With an interaction there is no simple interpretation of a "main effect." Thus you can't really compare the "significance" of that coefficient against the "significance" of the interaction coefficient, as you seem to be trying to do. Evaluate the model overall, not the individual "main effect" coefficients.