# R vs. JMP results for glms with interactions

Tags: r, regression, jmp

I am new to R and am trying to build general linear models with multiple categorical and continuous predictors using the lm() function. My models also have some interactions of the different categorical variables

Since I am learning R, I like to verify my results in JMP as I perform my analyses. In short, when I build the model in R, I get different parameter estimates and p-values compared to when I run the model in JMP.

This is how I run my R model and the output I get:

```
WBC_model<-lm(logWBC~Infection+Sex+Species+Infection*Sex+Infection*Species, data = WARBLER)
```

[image]

This is what I get from JMP with the same data:
[image]

Most of the parameter estimates and p-values are different (but not all of them), and I don't understand why. I notice however, that when I change the JMP modeling type to "ordinal" as opposed to nominal, I get the same results. I'm doing a lot of independent learning of statistics on my own, so if anyone could help me understand what is going on here, it would be most appreciated!

**Edited 11-19 with JMP output

[image]

Comment: Ok, I think it is just the reference levels. JMP has an option to switch how categorical variables are stored from nominal to ordinal. I think all that does is change the reference level, as like you said, ordinal vs. dependent shouldn't matter for the dichotomous categorical IVs. I have updated my post with the 2nd JMP output. This is what I'm still confused about: (1) why do the interactions have the same p-values in both examples, but the categorical variables on their own do not and (2) how do I decide which example is appropriate to use for the questions I hope to answer? @PeterFlom

Comment: The output of `anova(WBC_model)` should correspond to the JMP effect tests (depending on if JMP does Type I ANOVA).

Answer (score 3):

One thing that is definitely happening is that JMP and R are, by default, picking different reference levels. E.g. the parameter estimate for infection in R is for InfectionY, in JMP it is for InfectionN. This also affects interactions.

I'm not sure what is you mean by "changing the modelling type to ordinal".  If you mean changing multinomial regression to ordinal regression then that will surely have an effect on all results.  But that doesn't make much sense since the DV is continuous. And the categorical IVs are all dichotomous, so ordinal vs. nominal won't really matter for them.

What code are you using for JMP?

Answer (score 2):

When a predictor is involved in interactions, all its coefficient values (except for the highest-level interaction) depend on how its *interacting* predictors are coded. In your situation with categorical predictors, that depends on the choice of reference levels for its interacting predictors, as Peter Flom points out (+1). The same thing can happen with an interaction with a continuous predictor, [depending on whether the interacting continuous predictor is centered](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/417159/28500).

It's easy to confuse the initial report of model coefficients, which depend on the predictor-coding choices, with the model as a whole. We see that often on this site. Despite the differences in coefficient estimates, both your JMP and R models should give the same modeled outcome predictions for any combination of predictor-variable values. They are the same models, just expressed in different ways.

In particular, for a predictor involved in an interaction you can't depend on its individual coefficient estimate as a measure of its overall significance: the apparent "significance" of any lower-level coefficient involving it depends on how its *interacting* predictors are coded. For an overall estimate of predictor importance you need a "[chunk test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/28500)" that involves *all* the coefficients involving the predictor.