# Why does centering NOT cure multicollinearity?

Tags: multicollinearity, centering

In several posts, such as [Is centering a valid solution for multicollinearity?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95404/is-centering-a-valid-solution-for-multicollinearity), it states that centering doesn't solve multicollinearity because "it's a linear transformation."

I just made up a simple example. Consider
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Clearly, the columns are linear dependent here, hence we have multicollinearity. If you were to center $X$, you get
$$
X = \begin{bmatrix}
0.5 & 1\\
0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now the columns are no longer linear dependent, and the data matrix is full column rank. So doesn't centering, at times, solve multicollinearity?

Comment: You misinterpret the meaning of "it's a linear transformation:" in the context, the point was it's a linear transformation *of a single variable at a time.*  Any degree of multicollinearity, short of perfect linear dependence, *always* can be removed with a suitable linear transformation *of all the variables simultaneously.*  Your example is incorrect: the centered model matrix is $\pmatrix{1/2&1\\-1/2&-1}$ which is still singular.

Comment: @whuber Are you saying that if there's perfect multicollinearity, then suitable linear transformations of all variables can no longer remove the multicollinearity? Also, if it was the linear transformation of a single variable at a time, wouldn't the matrix actually be (assuming we center the second variable only) $$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & =1
\end{bmatrix}
$$? In which case would be full rank.

Comment: Centering is allowable only when the range of $X$ includes the constant vector. (That's because centering is a linear combination of a column vector and the constant vector and that will leave the model unaffected only when the constant vector is already in the model.) That's not the case with your $X,$ so it's an invalid example.  As far as the linear transformation claim goes, that's basic linear algebra: a linear transformation can never increase the dimension of a subspace. Perfect collinearity means the image of $X$ is a subspace of smaller dimension than the number of variables, *QED.*