# Stepwise model selection using Generalized Akaike Information Criterion

Tags: model-selection, generalized-additive-model, gamlss

I run a series of models using [gamlss](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss/index.html) `stepGAIC()` model selection. The problem that I have is that in `gamlss`, `stepGAIC()` uses AIC values to select the variables in the model. Since my sample size is considered small I probably need to use the [AICc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc) values to select the best model. I don’t know if I would be able to create models using AIC and select from those models the best based on AICc.

Comment: Just for reference: stepwise model selection in many cases is a bad idea, see http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/35989 , so you should consider if it is what you really want to do. For alternatives check: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13686/what-are-modern-easily-used-alternatives-to-stepwise-regression

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can't select "the best" model using stepwise regression. *All* statistics produced through stepwise model building have a nested chain of invisible/unstated "conditional on excluding *X*" or "conditional on including *X*" statements built into them with the result that:

- *p*-values are biased
- variances are biased
- parameter estimates are biased
- *F* statistics are biased
- false predictors are likely to be included
- true predictors are likely to be excluded

So, while you could use AIC as a stepwise model building, the consequences of doing so are unreliable and likely invalid model inferences.

Answer (score 0):

[AICc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc) is given as:

$AICc = AIC + \frac{2k(k + 1)}{n - k + 1}$

where n is the sample size and k is the number of parameters being estimated. You could just create the multiple models you are interested in, then manually calculate the AICc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already did that but my dilemma is that if I should use AICc for selecting the variables in my models rather than the default AIC used in the stepGAIC function in GAMLSS.