# statsmodels logistic regression with binned variables has large coefficients and standard error for some variables

Tags: logistic, python, regression-coefficients, convergence, binning

I'm fitting a logistic regression (binary) using Python's `statsmodels`, and here's a snippet of summary from the model:

[image]

I have noticed that the large coefficients only occurred on two variables and it seems like it's due to not converging (though I set max to 500).

> Warning: Maximum number of iterations has been exceeded.
>            Current function value: 0.094121
>            Iterations: 500

I'm wondering what's the reason behind it and what are some possible ways of fixing this.

Just as extra information, I did:

1. drop one of the levels from binning
2. add a constant to the design matrix

Any help is appreciated! And please let me know what other information might be useful to identify the problem.

Comment: Did you look into separation? See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180447/is-this-really-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression-or-is-something-else-g  and search this site.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good application for binning.  To have an adequate fit for an underlying smooth relationship that is steep in places, binning requires a large number of bins resulting in a losing battle in the bias-variance war because of high variance.  For continuous variables use fewer parameters and still get a better fit using things like restricted cubic splines and other cubic spline bases.

Answer (score 0):

Your factors may are nested within each other, check the model variance inflation factor (VIF). This correlation leads to high errors, since you have many factors there is a considerable chance of nesting.

It is equivalent of collinearity between continuous variables, but in your case correlation between factors.

Good luck!

Best,
VMaia

Comment: I checked VIF for variables before binning and all variables have VIF of ~1, should I do that for all the binary bins after splitting as well?

Comment: I think it is worth to try, but maybe nesting is not the problem.

Comment: Interestingly, I checked correlation between all the bins from the two variables with huge coefficients but there's no obvious high correlations. I'm wondering if there are any other possible causes.

Comment: Did you run a VIF for the whole model, containing all variables?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from endorsing Frank's comment that binning is seldom a good idea and certainly not to this extent the most likely explanation, as mentioned by Kjetil in a comment is that the model suffers from separation. For some combination of levels the outcome variable is all zero or all one. A typical symptom of this is the coefficients trying got go off to infinity until the software calls a halt and very large standard errors.

Assuming it is separation then advice is available [How to deal with perfect separation in logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) where in my opinion the answer by scortchi is the best advice.