# When can one use Hochberg's or Hommel's method for adjusting P values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, assumptions

The `p.adjust` function in R can produce P value adjustments based on methods from Hochberg and Hommel, which are both more powerful than methods from Bonferroni and Holm. However, and as stated in the R documentation:

> Hochberg's and Hommel's methods are valid when the hypothesis tests
>   are independent or when they are non-negatively associated (Sarkar,
>   1998; Sarkar and Chang, 1997).

Can anyone explain what this means in a more accessible language?

Also, is there a way to empirically determine whether your hypothesis tests (data) meet this assumption?

Comment: You might want to see my related question and whuber's answer at [Plain language meaning of "dependent" and "independent" tests in the multiple comparisons literature?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137337/plain-language-meaning-of-dependent-and-independent-tests-in-the-multiple-co)