# Slight confusion on independent vs dependent samples

Tags: categorical-data, independence

If I have two patient populations with cancer and I'm comparing cancer sizes, so say cancer size 1, 2 and 3 in an ordered fashion. Would these samples be dependent or independent? In one way, these are all separate patients but to be in size 2 you can't ever be in size 1 so that's where I'm confused if they are dependent then?

Comment: Related [Plain language meaning of “dependent” and “independent” tests in the multiple comparisons literature?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137337)