# Do I need to do bonferroni correction for one-way anova?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova

I have 30 classification models. I am checking whether their mean error rates are equal(null hypothesis H0) or whether there is some model which is different(atleast one mean isnt equal, H1).

My significance level is 0.05. Do i need to account for the fact that i have 30 models and correct it to 0.5/30 although I am only testing 1 hypothesis?

I have done 5 fold cross validation and fed the data to `stats.f_oneway` function in python

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88065.

Comment: Yes, while that post makes sense; with respect to ANOVA do we need to use it as ANOVA considers multiple models but there is only one hypothesis in my case?

Comment: If you truly are testing that one hypothesis, it sounds like you are using ANOVA in its default mode exactly as intended.  There isn't any multiple testing to be corrected for.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused as to whether i should consider multiple hypothesis correction due to multiple models, which clearly isnt needed now.