# Testing if proportion is larger than mean

Tags: r, statistical-significance, proportion

After reading several posts on this site, I am still not sure on how to proceed. I have a set of genes, and have the proportion of mutated sites in each of them. This is an example in R:

```
myStats<- data.frame(
  SampleName = paste(
    'GeneName', 1:9, sep = ''),
  PropOfMutations = c(
    0.12210201, 0.13885505, 0.12861272,
    0.12845850, 0.14886364, 0.10860927,
    0.12933458, 0.08028169, 0.08295195))
```

I am using proportions as each gene has different length, and each of its  nucleotides has a chance to mutate.

I want to test if any of the genes has a proportion of mutations higher than expected, as compared to the whole dataset. Would it be correct in this case to use the z-test:

```
z <- (p-p0)/sqrt(p0(1-p0)/n)
```

where n is the total no. of genes I have, and p0 the mean of all values? Please let me know if I need to add any additional details.

I have also checked the distribution of my data:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If we abstractly name each site with a color and fancifully use the word "jelly bean" for "gene," you will appreciate that your situation is exactly the one described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88065.

Comment: Thank you, I would definitely need to correct for multiple testing here :)