# Average of root mean square error

Tags: rms

Is taking the average of different rmse valid? for example 
                  average rmse = (rmse1+rmse2+rmse3)/3
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Valid for what exactly? Sure, you can average them [you can multiply them, too](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/432/7290).

Comment: if for example I want to know which is the best among different models and I get the rmse for three different input to each model. Therefore I have 3 rmse for each. Is it correct to just average the three rmse's in able to select the best model?

Comment: Its answer lies in reading sampling theory.

Comment: better than just taking the ordinary average I mean. Or not?

Answer (score 4):

I actually wasn't sure about this either so I tested it out with a short example:

```
## Create simple function to calcualte the error
rmse <- function(error){sqrt(mean(error^2))}

## Define two example error vectors
error1 <- c(0.4, 0.2, 0.01)
error2 <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.79)

## Find the RMSE of each error vector
rmse1 <- rmse(error1)
rmse2 <- rmse(error2)

## Compare the RMSE variants
print(rmse_all <- rmse(c(error1, error2)))
[1] 0.3924708
print(rmse_avg <- mean(rmse1, rmse2))
[1] 0.2582634
```

So we can se that **they are not equal**.

```
## As described by @whuber in the comments:
                                                 
a <- rmse1^2*length(error1)                 # - square each rmse & multiply
b <- rmse2^2*length(error2)                 #   it by its associated count
c <- sum(a, b)                             # - sum that stuff up,                  
d <- c/sum(length(error1), length(error2))   # - divide by the total count,          
print(total_rmse <- sqrt(d))               # - take the square root.
[1] 0.3924708
```

Comment: The answer lies in front of you.  Since you have defined rmse as the root of the mean of certain values, then just square each rmse, multiply it by its associated count, sum that stuff up, divide by the total count, and take the square root.  The "slight bastardization" can be dreadfully wrong.

Comment: @whuber - I have edited to show what you describe. Please feel free edit my post with comments to add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you do not have the actual errors, only the RMSE statistic, I guess an improvement on taking the simple mean might be to use the geometric mean. This makes the assumption that each RMSE score deserves the same weight.

```
rmse1
[1] 0.2582634
rmse2
[1] 0.4912908
(rmse1*rmse2)^(1/2)
[1] 0.3562056
```

Comment: "OK" in what sense??