# source info for a cartoon

Tags: barplot

[image]

I want to use this image in a presentation for teachers and I cant find the source, when I drop it in google images your site comes up, any idea of the source?

Comment: (I understand the rationale for calling this thread off topic, but IMHO, it's probably OK to stay open.)

Answer (score 4):

The source is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19944/67822), referencing [Andrew Gelman's blog](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/12/16/suspicious-histograms/), referencing [this](http://velica.deviantart.com/art/Error-bars-101948712). You can get it as a t-shirt.